# Formula using fibonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction, fibonacci-numbers

Let $a_n$ be the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence defined recursively by
 $a_{n+1} = \frac {1}{1+a_n}$

and let $a_1 = 1.$ Find a formula for $a_n$ in terms of the Fibonacci numbers $F_n$. Prove that the formula you found is valid for all natural numbers $n.$

Wow can I solve this type of problem?

And, how to prove it by induction? Do i solve for $a_n$ or what? I'm new to this chaper( sequences and series).

Comment: I don't understand you use of \ in there.

Comment: Hint: Calculate the first few terms of $a(n)$ and see if you notice a pattern there.

Comment: Oh / means division pardon me i'm new here

Comment: Division is a forward slash as you wrote in your comment, not a backslash as in the text of the question.  I also suspect that you meant $a(n+1)=1/(1+a(n))$, not what you wrote  which simply says $a(n+1)=(1/1)+a(n)$ which would give $a(n+1)=n+1$.  Please pay attention to the order of operations or use parentheses to make sure it comes out right.  Have you just computed a few dozen terms in a spreadsheet?

Comment: I suggest you grind through the first few terms of your sequence, to find a pattern.  When you think you have your pattern, you write your proposition. e.g. $a_n = F_n\cdot F_{n+1}$ (This is not the correct proposition by the way, I just have it here as an example.)  Now you need to prove your proposition is true.  You will have already covered the base case testing the first few elements.  Now, assume that the proposition is true for the abstract case of $n$ and show that if the assumption is accurate, the proposition also hold for $n+1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I see a recurrence relation where $a_{n+1}$ depends on $a_n$ as a linear fraction. I will write $a_n$ as a ratio $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ for two other sequences $(p_n)$ and $(q_n)$ to be determined. Simplify the relation and see what I can get.

For the recurrence relation at hand, we have

$$\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}} = a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{1+a_n} = \frac{q_n}{q_n + p_n}$$

If the two sequences $(p_n)$, $(q_n)$ satisfies
$$\begin{cases}
p_{n+1} &= q_n\\
q_{n+1} &= q_n + p_n
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}
p_{n+1} &= q_n\\
q_{n+1} &= q_n + q_{n-1}
\end{cases},
\quad\text{ for }n > 1
$$
then $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ will be a solution of original recurrence relation.

Notice the recurrence relation for $q_n$ is the one for Fiboniacci numbers.
One should be able to express $q_n$ and hence $p_n$ in terms of Fibonacci numbers. Since $a_1 = 1$, we can take 
$$p_1 = q_1 = 1 \quad\iff\quad q_0 = q_1 = 1$$ 
Now $F_1 = F_2 = 1$, it suggest us to pick
$$\begin{cases}p_n &= F_n,\\ q_n &= F_{n+1}\end{cases}
\quad\iff\quad
a_n = \frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}
$$
Up to this point, we haven't proved $a_n$ is given by above expression. We only have an ansatz of what $a_n$ should be. By direct subsitution, we can verify
this ansatz do satisfy the original recurrence relation.

$$a_1 = \frac{F_1}{F_2} = 1\quad\text{ and }\quad 
a_{n+1} = \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_{n+2}} = \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_{n+1} + F_{n}} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}} = \frac{1}{1 + a_n}$$

Comment: +1 for solving my problem. Since you did it in a comment I'm breaking the rules and up voting here :)

Comment: @user135711 thanks, I hope this answer is at least worthy to be upvoted. BTW, don't do this next time or some mod will be running after you ;-p

Comment: I liked what you've done here so much that I went ahead and applied your idea to the more general case $f_{n+1} = \frac{1}{a+bf_n}$. It worked out quite nicely, although it's a bit more involved. This entailed more generalized forms of the Fibonacci sequence, as I have described here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301198/how-to-solve-initial-value-problem-for-recurrence-relation-when-both-condition/2303196#2303196, for example.

Comment: @CyeWaldman thanks, I'm glad you will find idea useful. BTW, about the answer you linked, you forget to deal with the special case $\alpha = \beta$.

Comment: @achillehui That's a fair question. It can easily happen if $b=-a^2/4$. At first I thought it would be an impossible situation but it's not. It turns out to have only the *Lucas*-type term and it supports but a single initial condition. The reason for that is that the *Fibonacci*-type term goes to zero as, say, $\beta\to\alpha$ because $\alpha-\beta$ divides $\alpha^n-\beta^n$. The you are left with $f_n=(af_0/2)L_n=(af_0/2)\alpha^{n-1}$.

Comment: @CyeWaldman Hmm.. when $\alpha \to \beta$, I think one should replace $F_n$ by $n\alpha^{n-1}$ instead of $0$. In that way, the formula $f_n = \left(f_1 - \frac{af_0}{2}\right)n\alpha^{n-1} + \left(\frac{af_0}{2}\right)\alpha^{n-1}$ will reproduce the correct value at  $n = 0, 1, 2$.

Comment: @achillehui Yes, I actually just rethinking this right now. I have to reconsider it and look at the binomial expansion of $F_n$ when you divide out the denominator. To be continued. (Will I ever break away from this computer?)

Comment: @achillehui Hey, I have verified your solution for $\alpha=\beta$. Thanks very much, it's been an interesting exercise all around.

Answer (score 3):

By induction $a_n=\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}$ because $a_1=\frac{F_1}{F_2}=1$ and
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+a_n}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}}=\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_{n+2}}.$$

$\{F_n\}:1,1,2,3,5,...$.